# Adding custom calendar to the Google calendar using ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-calendar-api

I have tried using EKCalendar. But I am not able to create calendar using EKCalendar on Gmail and Outlook. Then I have done some analysis to create google calendar using iOS, found a solution as Google Calendar API. Is there any other way to sync google calendar and creating calendar from apple calendar to google and adding custom events to google calendar from iPad? please give some solutions regarding this!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to edit a Google calendar using IOS (and I think it's not possible, except using Safari Browser which is not practical) but to synchronize it : https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/151674?hl=en